# DB Use gives problems... SP migrated by Flyway produces MySQL syntax error while corresponding raw script does not

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, flyway, amazon-aurora

Using Flyway to do mysql migration. I migrate a stored procedure, it successfully migrates/deploys but when running gives an error.

If I deploy the same stored procedure manually from MySQL Workbench or another tool, it runs fine.

I am wondering how other users are using Flyway with mysql without running into this problem

I tried removing comments etc from the stored procedure. No avail.

Comment: Hi -- in order to answer this question, people will need more specifics. What are the errors? What differences show in a dump of the SP produced by each of the migrations?

Comment: There is no difference in dump of SP between the one migrated using flyway and one deployed manually using mysql command. But. after deploying it using flyway... when the StoredProc is called it throws this error : Error Code: 1292
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value.  after deploying it using mysql command... it returns desired resultset with no errors